# PHP -Multibyte regular expression to remove all but chinese characters...please help

Tags: php, regex, string, utf-8, posix

I am trying to take a UTF-8 string that looks something like:

> &q| 艝隭)R墢Lq28}徫廵g'Y鑽妽踒F

and strip out everything except the Chinese characters they are hex 4E00-9FA5 and I would like to keep only those characters in the string. I have tried taking this line that leaves only valid US characters:

```
preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7E]/', '', $str);
```

to this:

```
preg_replace('/[^\x4E00-\x9FA5]/u', '', $str);
```

but it outputs nothing....am I missing something? I am not very good with regular expressions

Comment: Also when I try using mb_eregi_replace(); with or without the /u modifier (to my understanding mb_eregi_replace should already have multibyte support, I get no error but my string remains unchanged.

Comment: Those characters don't make sense in Chinese. It's more likely you're using the wrong encoding.

Comment: You say that you've got a UTF-8 string, but then that you're interested in the range 4e00-9fa5.  That range refers to the unicode values (UCS-2) but not to UTF-8 streams, which are a way of encoding unicode.  You can tell this since, for example, the sequence 4e 00 in UTF-8 is two characters not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close!

```
preg_replace('/[^\x{4E00}-\x{9FA5}]/u', '', $str);
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this: function.preg-replace: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 12...i have set php.ini mbstring.internal_encoding=UTF-8 is there something else i missed?

Comment: Any suggestions? I appreciate any help

Comment: It did not remove any characters from the string in your example...?

Comment: What PHP version are you using? the u modifer should stop that kind of compilation error... Also, make sure your input is UTF-8 and not something else.

Comment: PHP 5, I have have called like so : utf8_encode($str) then your preg_replace regular expression. No error after utf8_encode, however my output is empty

Comment: Also after utf8_encode(); my text appears to be the same as it was before

Comment: Paul, your solution is correct. However, I am working with a larger string (about 3000 characters) there is something in that string preg_replace must not like...if I use your expression on the string I pasted into this question, it gives me exactly what I want. Any suggestions to how I can make preg_replace work on this string? I know it is not the length of the string I have use preg_replace on 2MB txt files before with no issues. Any ideas? And Thanks again for your help

Comment: Without seeing your test string I can't really say, only suggest that the string contains characters out of that range perhaps or that parts / it didn't need encoding?

Comment: $str = (mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8') == 'UTF-8') ? $str : utf8_encode($str); // Might help?